# refresh the table after update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React so please forgive me if this issue is entry-level to you.

Basically, I want to do the thing as the title goes,

here I have a function designed for this purpose:

```
function saveAndUpdate() {
// data processing and wrap up the finalized data, lets call it newData
    useEffect(() => {
        async function loadData() {
            try {
                await axios.put(API/updateEntry,{objToUpdate: newData}).then(() => {
                    const { loading, error, data } = axios.get(API/dataForTheTable)
                    callback(data);
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }
        loadData();
    }, []);
}
```

callback is a function in parent component in order to update the state related to the data immediately after the data is updated.

```
const handleCallback = (data) => {
    setInfo(data);
}
```

And by running this, I get the classic error which I still do not fully understand:

Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Where did you declare the `callback` function?. Is it above/below `saveAndUpdate` function?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that what you're doing is creating a hook (`saveAndUpdate`) and trying to access to It somewhere (for example, inside another hook or function).

Althought, a hook to update data (with axios.put, where you need to pass an argument; the data for the update) is not a good approach, as an UseEffect hook will run when the component is mounted, not when the user clicks on a button or whatever. For example, it would be better if you use this for gathering data (get request) from your backend when the component mounts.

Anyway this is a way you could do what you want to achieve, using the useCallback. I've created a button that fires the function and pass some data (just you can see the expected behaviour):

In the `saveAndUpdate` hook (name it as `useSaveAndUpdate`, just a convention for hooks names):

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function useSaveAndUpdate(dataUpdate) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [updating, setUpdating] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (updating) {
      const req = function () {
        // the put request (dataUpdate will be the data we use for the request)...
       // for this i'm just going to set data to the argument we've passed
       // the idea is to setData to the returned data from the server
        setData(dataUpdate);
        setUpdating(false);
        // setting updating to false, if there's a re-render it won't do the request again
      };
      req();
    }
  }, [updating, dataUpdate]);

  return [data, updating, setUpdating];
}
```

In the parent component:

```
import { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import useSaveAndUpdate from './useSaveAndUpdate'

const parent = () => {

  const [updateTarget,setUpdateTarget = useState(null)

  const [data,updating,setUpdating] = useSaveAndUpdate(updateTarget)

  const updateFunction = useCallback((updateData) => {
    setUpdating(true)
    //
    // ^ Setting updating to true will fire the request inside useSaveAndUpdate when re-render
    //
    setUpdateTarget(updateData)
    // Setting the data for the update (this data will be used in the put request)
  },[setUpdating,setUpdateTarget])

  return (
    <h3>{loading?'loading...':'not loading'}</h3>
    <h3>{data?data.name:'data is null'}</h3>
    {/*data will be updated when button clicked, so if it's a table just do data.map()...*/}
    <button onClick={() => updateFunction({name:'jhon'})}>Click me to update</button>
  )
}
```

So at first render, It will outpout that It's not loading and data is null.
When click It'll say loading for a sec (the time the request lasts), and the data will be displayed ('jhon').

A small [codesandbox so you can see how it works](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-heisenberg-kf5ezm?file=/src/App.js).